# How to select the software's version in gentoo by emerge?

Tags: linux, gentoo

I want to install django 1.4, but the default install version is 1.3.2, how can I change the version to install.

I only know that to change dir to /usr/portage/dev-python/django and install the django1.4's `.ebuild` file

Is there another way? I read the use flag document but not found the way...

Comment: maybe this fits better on serverfault?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this :

```
emerge =django-1.4
```

Comment: I read the man emerge and find the answer just now, in `man emerge`, search `atom`, and that is the usage to appoint the version

Answer (score 5):

You can check what package versions are available:

```
equery list -po vim
```

Select required package with atom notation

```
emerge -av =app-editors/vim-7.4.273
```

Answer (score 1):

emerge -av =dev-python/django-1.4

As long as there is an ebuild available, it will be merged or show a hint about unmasking the requested version number. For our example this should do the trick:

```
echo =dev-python/django-1.4 >> /etc/portage/package.keywords
```

To stick with that version, be sure to mask higher versions by adding an entry to /etc/portage/package.mask:

```
echo >=dev-python/django-1.4 >> /etc/portage/package.mask
```

but careful with that... it might break updates in the future...

Comment: And what if there is no ebuild available?